# How can I get access to password hashing in postgresql? Tried installing postgresql-contrib in ubuntu, still can't access hashing functions

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

So I'm trying to just hash some passwords in postgresql, and the only hashing solution that I've found for postgresql is part of the pgcrytpo package ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/pgcrypto.html ) that is supposed to be in postgresql-contrib ( http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/contrib.html ).

So I installed postgresql-contrib, (sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib), restarted my server (as a simple way to restart postgresql).

However, I still don't have access to any of the functions for hashing that are supposed to be in postgresql-contrib, e.g.:

```
ninjawars=# select crypt('global salt' || 'new password' || 'user created date', gen_salt('sha256'));
ERROR:  function gen_salt(unknown) does not exist

ninjawars=# select digest('test', 'sha256') from players limit 1;
ERROR:  function digest(unknown, unknown) does not exist

ninjawars=# select hmac('test', 'sha256') from players limit 1;
ERROR:  function hmac(unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

So how can I hash passwords in postgresql, on ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be a hint, from one of the web pages you listed above:

> Many modules supply new user-defined
>   functions, operators, or types. To
>   make use of one of these modules,
>   after you have installed the code you
>   need to register the new objects in
>   the database system by running the SQL
>   commands in the .sql file supplied by
>   the module. For example,
>
> ```
> psql -d dbname -f SHAREDIR/contrib/module.sql
> ```

Comment: Gracias, that does explain it.

Answer (score 4):

After you install postgresql-contrib you need to run `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;` against the db where you want to use the crypto functions

Comment: Although `pgcrypto` looks like already installed, it needs to be installed again. Strange. But it helped me, 10x.

Comment: yes, it has to be enabled for each db you want to use it on

Answer (score 2):

Much easier Just install pdAdmin and from the database you are working on right click on the database and ADD NEW OBJECT select Extension then select pgcrypto for name and set the definition schema to public and version 1.0 WORKED AS A CHARM FOR ME ON MY MAC OS 10.7.5 using Postgres 9.2

Comment: Yeah, they seem to have updated the system to make extensions easier to manage, happily, and now after installing postgresql-contrib in postgres 9.1 and up you can just:
`create extension pgcrypto` or from the command line
`echo "create extension pgcrypto" | psql -d dataBaseName`
to enable extensions, as well.